# Syntax error during calculate field between two long integer fields

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcmap, field-calculator, arcgis-10.7

I keep getting an error when trying to run a calculate field section of my code. I'm trying to simply add values from two long integer fields (Speed and Lanes) into a newly added field (Stress_Calc). I know that it has to be with the syntax of my expression. I have tried several different formatting combinations to try and get the code to work.

Below I will list the different combinations of formats of the expressions I have tried and the results that come out of them :

```
"!Speed! + !Lanes!" = ERORR 999999 
'!Speed! + !Lanes!' = ERORR 999999
"'!Speed!' + '!Lanes!'" = ERORR 999999 
'"!Speed!" + "!Lanes!"' = No error but the calculation does not occur
```

Code listed:

```
arcpy.AddField_management(MergeNetwork, "Stress_Calc", "LONG")
StressCalcExp = '"!Speed!" + "!Lanes!"'
StressCalc = arcpy.CalculateField_management(MergeNetwork, "Stress_Calc", StressCalcExp)
```

Comment: Python 9.3 is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [help section for Calculate Field](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.7/tools/data-management-toolbox/calculate-field.htm). Visual Basic is default `expression type` and will be used when you dont specify other:

> VB —The expression will be written in a standard VB format. This is
>   the default.

The syntax is different if using VB or Python. Looks like you are trying a python expression (!-signs enclosing fieldname). Try:

`arcpy.CalculateField_management(in_table = MergeNetwork, field = "Stress_Calc", expression = "!Speed! + !Lanes!", expression_type = 'PYTHON')`